# setting tab order for custom widgets not working

Tags: qt, qwidget

[image]Im trying to set the tab order for the Custom widget im adding on the widget created by designer.

I used scrollArea and a line edit . so when the user enter 10, 10 custom widgets will be added to the scroll area.

I set the scrollArea tab no as ex:5 and 6,7 and 8 to the ok , cancel, clear push buttons.

when the text entered in the edit 
entries = LineEdit entry.

```
while(entries)
    {
        SpeciesInfo *SpeciesParent = new SpeciesInfo(this);

        m_speciesList<<SpeciesParent;

        scrollLayout->addWidget(SpeciesParent); //Entries added to scrollarea layout


        entries --;
    }



    ui.speciesScrollArea->setFocusProxy(m_speciesList.at(0));
    ui.speciesScrollArea->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
```

but the taborder is coming to speciesInFo only after ok,cancel and clear button. tab order is not coming inside the speciesInfo when it reach the tab on ScrollArea.

inside SpeciesInfo policy setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);

Comment: You may have met a limitation of Qt here. Here something similar has been tried without success: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33760978/3021018